# Java Fast Sine Wave Tone

Tags: java, audio, wave, trigonometry

I'm looking for an example on how to generate and play a Sine Audio Wave in Java.  I've found many other solutions on StackOverflow and around the web, but none have been able to produce and play a wave as quick as I need it (1.92 ms length, with 0 ms between).  I'll only need two different waves (one at 2083.3 Hz, the other at 1565.5 Hz), so the project would allow storing an array or similar to save calculation time, if needed.

Comment: No, I wish to generate a Tone of a specified frequency.

Comment: You should check this link : http://vermeille.fr/dotclear2/ It's not in java but it's a good start

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with the existing examples that do, indeed, abound. What do you mean they don't play "quick" enough? Do they not start fast enough in response to something?

Comment: He's trying to make a blue-box or a soft-modem in Java. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Wolin Labs](http://www.wolinlabs.com/blog/java.sine.wave.html) seems to have covered this one at the link. Looks like they just use the [java. sound.sampled.SourceDataLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html) to create a tone with its source being a sine wave function. Frequency can be changed as well.

Comment: I found that resource before.  It works, but if I remember right its timing isn't exact, the example even says about 5 seconds :), I'm looking for something pretty specific.